# What is CPN in youtube video

Tags: youtube, nonce

The context menu which appears after RMB click has one option named Stats for nerds after which another menu appears on the left top corner.

One of the parameter associated is CPN. 
What does that mean?

Comment: Channel Privacy Number maybe?

Comment: @ihsancemil I dont think so since it changes each time you refresh the video, but I am not sure.

Comment: Client Playback Nonce

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As answered officially [on reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/781tel/what_do_the_stats_for_nerds_mean_such_as_here/doqgely/):

> CPN is just a string we use to identify the playback; if you have
>   problems with the playback, developers can use it to look up log/stats
>   information on the playback so we can figure out what went wrong.

and in the same [comment tree](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/781tel/what_do_the_stats_for_nerds_mean_such_as_here/doqljir/):

> Yes, CPN is just a unique playback ID, computed on the client; stands
>   for "Client Playback Nonce."